# Android NDK thread aborts program

Tags: android, multithreading, sdk, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Why does this c++ (NDK) thread brings the whole program down ?

```
{   
sleep(2);

// The JNIEnv
JNIEnv* jenv = NULL;

// attach thread to running JVM
int err = jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&jenv, NULL);

char szerr[256];
sprintf(szerr, "AttachCurrentThread() returned: %d", err);

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "MYPROG", szerr);

jvm->DetachCurrentThread();

sleep (5);
}
```

szerr is 0, and the program would not abort if I do not AttachCurrentThread. The abortion 
happens without any error being indicated in console / logcat.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.ndk/4687

Perhaps you should use `GetEnv()` to see if the environment is setup, before calling `AttachCurrentThread()` (otherwise no need to). More info [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/gingerbread-release/docs/jni-tips.html).

Comment: thank you, but I shan't pursue this anymore. I think I may have solved it btw... :/ Anyway, that stuff got abandoned.